# How to compress and resize an image during upload with GD Library?

Tags: php, file-upload, mysqli, gd, image-uploading

How can I compress and resize an image during upload using the GD Library?

In the current code, there is resize and compression attempted, but I failed to get it right. The image that is uploaded is black. Also I am able to upload the same name.jpg file, even though it already exists, the script should prevent that.

Hope you can help, I will learn a lot by it.

The following is the code:

```
// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form, but the logo is uploaded first
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        // logo definition
        $logoname = $_FILES["logo"]["name"];
        $logotmp_name = $_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"];
        $logotype = $_FILES["logo"]["type"];
        $logosize = $_FILES["logo"]["size"];
        $logoerror = $_FILES["logo"]["error"];
        $logofolder = "../images/";
        $logodestination = $logofolder . $logoname;
        // logo upload
        if(isset($logoerror)){ if($logoerror > 0){ echo "Error: " . $logoerror . "<br>"; } else {
        $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
        // verify logo extension
        $ext = pathinfo($logoname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");    
        // verify logo size - 5MB maximum
        $maxsize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; if($logosize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.");
        // verify MIME type of the logo
        if(in_array($logotype, $allowed)){
        // resize the image 
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($logotmp_name);
        // make the new image width of 600
        $newwidth = 600;
        // make the new image height of 400
        $newheight = 400;
        // It loads the images we use jpeg function you can use any function like imagecreatefromjpeg
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($logodestination);
        // Resize the $thumb image.
        imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
        // It then save the new image to the location specified by $logoname variable
        imagejpeg($thumb, $logodestination, 75); 
        // verify whether the logo already exists before uploading it
        if(file_exists($logofolder . $logoname)){ echo $logoname . " is already exists."; } else {
        move_uploaded_file($logotmp_name, $logofolder . $logoname);

        echo "Your file was uploaded successfully."; } } else { 
        echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file - please try again."; } } } else { 
        echo "Error: Invalid parameters - please contact your server administrator."; }
// get the form data and logo path
$rating = htmlentities($_POST['rating'], ENT_QUOTES);
$synopsis = htmlentities($_POST['synopsis'], ENT_QUOTES);
$age = htmlentities($_POST['age'], ENT_QUOTES);
$logo = "/images/".$logoname;
$active = htmlentities($_POST['active'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check that rating, synopsis, age, logo and active are not empty
if ($rating == '' || $synopsis == '' || $age == '' || $logo == '' || $active == '')
{
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($rating, $synopsis, $age, $logo, $active, $error);
}
else
{
// insert the new record into the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT age_ratings (rating, synopsis, age, logo, active) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $rating, $synopsis, $age, $logo, $active);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
}
```

Comment: while you are at least checking if the upload actually succeeded, the rest of your code simply assumes that nothing could ever go wrong. you don't check if the thumbnail was written out, you don't actually check if the move call succeed. you just pretend like it always will and proclaim success. And everyone knows that hanging a "mission accomplished" banner behind your head pretty much proves that the mission is far from accomplished.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am not a professional, but I tried googling what you meant. How should I check whether move_uploaded_file (if you refer to this as the move call) is succeeded? Also how to check if the thumbnail was written out? (I guess you are reffering to $thumb), please note that I am not trying to make a thumbnail, the tutorial I used was trying to save a resized thumbnail of the uploaded image in addition to the image. I tried applying logic and solving the script into resizing and compressing the uploaded file and then saving the same, single file, resized and compressed.

Comment: I found that perhaps: is_uploaded_file - is what you are refering to, can you please example how I can place it correctly in my script? I tried it and it didn't work. Also I updated my code in the post, I tried simplifying it a bit.

Comment: a lot of php functions return boolean false on failure. you need to check those return values.

Comment: I figured out that there is nothing wrong with my script, there is a problem with GD Library that it doesn't handle pictures below 92 dpi and there is a problem because of (dots: ".") in the path to save images to, it executes fine from the root directory, but not from any lower folders. Thanks for being so cool with your help. If you know a different way in making it work with all kinds of images and making it work for any directory, please help Mr. FB.

Comment: dpi is a conversion factor. it has nothing to do with image size. gd looks at the pixels and couldn't care less about dpi. the only thing dpi does is tell the display device how to display the pixels. e.g. a 100x100 pixel image at 100dpi is 1inch by 1nch. at 200dpi, it's 0.5inch x 0.5inch.